# Python function serach in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to do function with three parameter to count number of occurence of param1 and param2 on param3 (dataframe)

```
I solved my problem
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `pyspark` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: Why did you remove the problem? Now we have answer without question :-)

Comment: I didn't   remove i just modified my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this the solution of my problem

```
def my_function(a,b,df)
  count=0
for row in df.itertuples():
  if(row.a==a and row.b==b):
     count=count+1
  else:
    print("somthing")
return count
```

and i called the function my_function(1,2,mydataframe)

Answer (score 0):

```
def search(param1,param2, list):
    count=0
    for element in list:
        if element == param1 or element == param2:
            count=count+1
        else:
            print('not found')
    return count
```

Comment: how i applied on a dataframe i want to enter the dataframe in parametre

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def search(param1,param2, l1):
    count = 0
    for element in param1:
       if element in l1:
        count=count+1
    for element in param2:
       if element in l1:
        count=count+1
    return count
```

Comment: how i applied on a dataframe i want to enter the dataframe in parametre